# SQL table handler without server/client

Tags: linux, sql

I am looking for a **CLI** program for **Ubuntu 14.04** that will be able to use a file as a "database". I really don't get why every piece software I found so far has a "daemon" and a "client" part, when what I really want is just a local one, and since I don't really want random daemons running around my system, I need to start it, issue a command, then stop it... And that's just annoying.

So,

## Requirements:

- Runs on Ubuntu 14.04
- Does not have a daemon-client system, or handles transparently to the user
- Preferably does not have a username-password system, since, again, it's for local usage
- Runs from command-line

## Nice to have:

- Can export to csv

Thanks for the help, and sorry if my English is not great, it's not my first language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) might fit your requirements. It is an SQL database system that uses simple files as databases that are accessed without a client/server mechanism, just via the API of a library.

A [command-line application to access SQLite files](http://www.sqlite.org/cli.html) is provided on the project website, as well. One of its supported output modes is CSV.

I cannot currently try whether it actually runs on the indicated Ubuntu version, but it is pretty cross-platform-compatible.

Comment: Thanks a lot - it even was pre-installed on Ubuntu. Works as I expected!